# How to fix WebView to layout edges

Tags: android, webview

I have an app which uses webView. It's properties are fill parent. I comes full screen as well. But the problem is that when I drag it down, the webView can still be pushed down or up or any side even after its ends, which makes it look ugly. Can we make the webView fixed to the borders and locked so that it does not move beyond its end.? Please help, thanx in advance.

**EDIT:**

Here is one example image in which I have opened IMDB website in my WebView:

[image]

Now as we can see here, the webview/website starts from the place where KindleFire Ad starts. But when I dragged it down and right, I was able to move the webview to this position. Although if I leave it, it will again run back to the top, but what I want is that it shound not move after its ends, that means the Kindle Fire Ad should always be at the Top Left corner of the screen, even if user drags his finger on the screen. Hope I am understandable, please ask if I am not.

**Here is my Layout.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#074068"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/controls"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reload"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/reload"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stop"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/stop"
            android:layout_weight="1" />



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/front"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/front"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @MD please see updated ques. Hope I am clear, please ask if I am not.

Comment: @Ak also show me your layout plz

Comment: @MD Sorry for missing that. Added..

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Picture listener to webview and set appropriate properties. This will limit the scrolling of page
Sample code which implements PictureListener,

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setPictureListener(this);

@Override
@Deprecated
public void onNewPicture(android.webkit.WebView view, Picture picture) 
{
    webview.scrollTo(700, 600);     
}
```

You'll get some idea by trying this but this is not the solution what you want I think.
Change the webview layout width & height to match parent.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but solved by setting `webview` option like below

```
    mWebView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
    //mWebView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    //webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    //webSettings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);

    mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setTextSize(TextSize.NORMAL);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Log.v("here","here");
            view.scrollBy(0, view.getContentHeight());
        }
    });
```

This is working perfect in my case.